# Rails 3.2 & assets pipeline: JavaScript Compression in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to serve compressed js in development mode in Rails 3.2? Gemfile contains

```
      gem "closure-compiler"
```

and development.rb contains

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
  config.assets.compress = true
```

Have runned

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And, even though the compiled application.js is there in:

```
./public/assets/application/application.js
./public/assets/application/application.js.gz
./public/assets/jasmine_rails/application.js
./public/assets/jasmine_rails/application.js.gz
```

... it never gets served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration made it work:

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```